# How to find out which route was poped in didPopNext in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget which could open different popups. If one of these popups is closed `didPopNext` is called. Is there a way to find out which route was poped?

Answer (score -1):

RouteObserver class.

Check out the documentation here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html

Comment: That's exaclty what I use. But how can I find out the previous route when `didPopNext` is called?